# Ubuntu 16.04 occasionally hangs with screen off after switching TTYs or turning screen off for inactivity

Tags: 16.04, graphics, screen, tty, amd-graphics

Sometimes when I switch TTYs (also while switching between logged in users) or after the screen darkened and turned off, my screen goes/stays in standby mode and does no longer wake up. Actually the entire system crashes then because it does not react to anything any more (pressing e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>NUM-Lock</kbd> does not toggle the LEDs,).

The only thing that still works are the magic <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands which I then use to reboot the machine ("R-E-I-S-U-B").

I suspect a problem with my rather old AMD graphics card. It's also regularly turning the screen off and on briefly as if it would change the resolution on multiple occasions, like opening the System Settings window etc. Maybe hardware support for this model got (accidentally?) removed since 16.04, because before the upgrade it ran on 15.10 without these crashes. The fake resolution changes were present back then as well though. Using Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit, Unity desktop now.

My graphics:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV535 [Radeon X1650 PRO]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1600x1200@75.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV530 GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0
```

Excerpt from `syslog` around the last crash (caused by TTS switching between two logged on users) and before rebooting the system with REISUB:

```
Jul  4 18:52:18 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: gnome-session-binary[2706]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  4 18:52:18 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: message repeated 4 times: [ gnome-session-binary[2706]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed]
Jul  4 18:52:18 wolf-pack gnome-session-binary[2706]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  4 18:52:18 wolf-pack gnome-session-binary[2706]: message repeated 4 times: [ GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed]
Jul  4 18:52:18 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: gnome-session-binary[2706]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  4 18:52:18 wolf-pack gnome-session-binary[2706]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: (deja-dup-monitor:5126): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[2570]: (zeitgeist-fts:3365): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Error releasing name org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer: The connection is closed
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[2570]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:3365): WARNING **: zeitgeist-fts.vala:252: The connection is closed
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[2570]: (zeitgeist-daemon:3358): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Error releasing name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine: The connection is closed
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[2570]: #033[31m[16:52:20.036353 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:449: The connection is closed
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: (unity-fallback-mount-helper:2853): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: (deja-dup-monitor:5126): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: (deja-dup-monitor:5126): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: (deja-dup-monitor:5126): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: (deja-dup-monitor:5126): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Jul  4 18:52:20 wolf-pack gnome-session[2706]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:3347): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of lightdm.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 119...
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[1]: Started Session c5 of user lightdm.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[16791]: Reached target Paths.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[16791]: Reached target Timers.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[16791]: Reached target Sockets.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[16791]: Reached target Basic System.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[16791]: Reached target Default.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[16791]: Startup finished in 127ms.
Jul  4 18:52:24 wolf-pack systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 119.
Jul  4 18:52:25 wolf-pack org.a11y.atspi.Registry[16813]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Jul  4 18:52:27 wolf-pack dbus[689]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jul  4 18:52:28 wolf-pack rtkit-daemon[1829]: Successfully made thread 16859 of process 16859 (n/a) owned by '119' high priority at nice level -11.
Jul  4 18:52:28 wolf-pack rtkit-daemon[1829]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 3 users.
Jul  4 18:52:29 wolf-pack rtkit-daemon[1829]: Successfully made thread 16926 of process 16926 (n/a) owned by '119' high priority at nice level -11.
Jul  4 18:52:29 wolf-pack rtkit-daemon[1829]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 3 users.
Jul  4 18:52:29 wolf-pack pulseaudio[16926]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Stopped target Default.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1923]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 17186 (kill).
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Jul  4 18:52:42 wolf-pack systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of alphawolf.
Jul  4 18:52:52 wolf-pack pulseaudio[16859]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Jul  4 18:52:58 wolf-pack kernel: [ 2853.412116] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Jul  4 18:52:59 wolf-pack kernel: [ 2854.461708] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Jul  4 18:53:01 wolf-pack kernel: [ 2855.916207] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Jul  4 18:53:03 wolf-pack kernel: [ 2858.442002] sysrq: SysRq : Emergency Sync
Jul  4 18:53:03 wolf-pack kernel: [ 2858.457544] Emergency Sync complete
Jul  4 18:53:07 wolf-pack kernel: [ 2862.284760] sysrq: SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O
Jul  4 18:54:05 wolf-pack rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="750" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Please tell me what additional information and logs you need.

What is the cause of these crashes and how can I prevent them?

I already disabled turning the screen off after inactivity, but I can't forego switching TTYs every now and then.

Comment: Mine is continuously hanging if i don't set automatic `Lock` `On`

Answer (score 0):

I got on this site to see if I could find an answer to a very similar problem.  I didn't find an exact answer, however, your post and others got me to change my Video card.  Drivers went (with the hardware change) from a ATI r5480 (with the problem) to NV43  (to problem solved).

I am running desktop 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: In the future, something such as this response may better fit as a comment, as it doesn't really address the question, but may offer reasonable advice.